# cassandra compression allocates more disk space

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 3.7 and I was comparing disk space allocation for different compaction/compression configurations on a single Cassandra node, and the results I got was as follows:

```
            Configurations                            Size of Data Directory

 1. No Compression - Default Compaction (Size-tiered): 3428288 (Bytes)
 2. LZ4 Compressor - Size-tiered                     : 3456764 (Bytes)
 3. Deflate Compressor - Size-tiered                 : 3554636 (Bytes)
 4. Snappy Compressor  - Size-tiered                 : 3435320 (Bytes)
 5. LZ4 Compressor - Leveled                         : 4640088 (Bytes)
 6. Snappy Compressor  - Leveled                     : 5788312 (Bytes)
```

For the fill-up process, I'm using cqlsh COPY command from a csv file.

My question is how does enabling compression results in allocating more disk space than when running without compression ? And why does Leveled-Compaction allocates more memory than "Size-tiered"-Compaction while it should be better suited for Read intensive operations (less SStables searching) ?

Comment: I figures out that this could happen due to different compaction thresholds. For example, the size-tiered compaction is triggered whenever 4 files of the same file are present. However, the Leveled Compaction is triggered every time a "flush" to the memory table is triggered. Also leveled compaction seems to save the SStables in fragments, thus requires more disk space "during" the compaction